# cannot find value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I can't see where I am wrong with this code so I kindly ask for your help.
I have two arrays:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [description] => Generali di Proprieta'
        [idmov] => 34
        [mov] => Manutenzioni
        [total] => 8000
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [description] => Generali di Proprieta'
        [idmov] => 35
        [mov] => Assicurazioni
        [total] => 6000
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [description] => Generali di Proprieta'
        [idmov] => 36
        [mov] => Cancelleria Postali
        [total] => 1850
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [description] => Generali di Proprieta'
        [idmov] => 37
        [mov] => Bancarie passive
        [total] => 700
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [description] => Generali di Proprieta'
        [idmov] => 38
        [mov] => Amministrazione
        [total] => 15000
    )
)
```

and

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [center] => 8
        [caus] => 34
        [total] => 38175.04
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [center] => 8
        [caus] => 35
        [total] => 6132.00
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [center] => 8
        [caus] => 36
        [total] => 223.80
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [center] => 8
        [caus] => 37
        [total] => 114.70
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [center] => 8
        [caus] => 38
        [total] => 14625.07
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [center] => 8
        [caus] => 39
        [total] => 7450.48
    )
```

I use this function

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['caus'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

to look in array B for each item of array A with this code:

```
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    if(searchForId($voce_bdg[$i]['idmov'], $voce_actual)){
        $key=searchForId($voce_bdg[$i]['idmov'], $voce_actual);
        $actual=$voce_actual[$key]['importo'];
        echo '<td class="report">'.number_format($actual,2,',','.').'</td>';
     }else{
        echo '<td class="report">0,00</td>';
    }
}
```

It works for every item like a charm except for the first item where it returns 0.

Where am I wrong??

Thanks in advance for your help!
Lelio

Comment: Name variables in English that will make it more understandable for others.

Comment: AAAAAAHHHHH! I formatted your question readably, why did you undo it?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the variables names. Probably we did it concurrently :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP treats the index 0 as a `false`. As such, if you find your result in index zero, it won't pass the `if()` statement you have.

Since your function returns `null` if no record found, why not try to check for `null`?

```
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    // Use is_null() check below. If it is not null, it is found.
    // Also, instead of doing searchForId() twice, just do it once and check for the result.

    $key = searchForId($voce_bdg[$i]['idmov'], $voce_actual);

    if(! is_null ($key))
    {
        $actual = $voce_actual[$key]['importo'];
        echo '<td class="report">'.number_format($actual,2,',','.').'</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td class="report">0,00</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. "PHP treats the index 0 as a false. As such, if you find your result in index zero, it won't pass the if() statement you have." Never realized before! Thank you again!

Comment: if this works then its fine other wise you can simply use in_array(searchitem,arraylist). put what item from array 1 you want to search in param 1 and put array 2 in param 2.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: @dishwasherWithProgrammingSkill You cannot use `in_array()` in this case, because: 1. The second array is 2-dimensional; 2. We want to look at the inner array with key 'caus'; 3. We want to retrieve the key where the search item is found to be used later.

Comment: my bad didn't realize it was a multidimensional array, guess I should stick to dishwashing ;D

Answer (score 0):

try replacing operator === for ==

Comment: Already tried. No changes. The first idmov=34 that match caus=34 provides no results. All the following are ok both with === and ==

Answer (score 0):

It does return something. It return 0 since the key is 0. But your if() interpret it as a "false"

change

```
if(searchForId($voce_bdg[$i]['idmov'], $voce_actual)){
```

with

```
if(searchForId($voce_bdg[$i]['idmov'], $voce_actual) != null){
```